# On server MongoDB connection Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

185.83.144.180  i wrote my server ip on my mongoose connection strin,but i cant insert data on mongoDB. How can i fix it,

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testOne');

var FormSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:Number,
    name: String,
    created: { type:Date,default:Date.now }},{collection:"forms"}
);
```

[image]

2)Another question is i run server.js on my local, then i cant take json data on my html file.But i can take jsonplaceholder datas.

Comment: does your localhost works?

Comment: And also what error you are getting? Get the error printed like this, `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testOne', function(err) { if (err) { console.error(err); }});`

Comment: i want to reach my server ip, i cant reach it. I run on my server mongo db, but in my local server.js i cant reach it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to your remote server your connection string should be this instead of localhost.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://185.83.144.180');
```

And make sure your mongo port is reachable from your ip address.

Comment: i am sure, if you let me to show i can show you screen. Thanks

Comment: I think it is easy to solve this for you but i am not master as you.:) i try till 3 days